# Creating a GUI application that emulates as Console(Java)

Tags: java, process, console, external, processbuilder

I've recently started a project where I am required to start a external process from within my parent process. However, since the external process uses System.console(), it is unable to function properly as it is getting a null object in return. Both the external and parent applications are written in java and there is no chance that the external process can be modified in any way (as it is being produced by a third party)

Both the Input and Output streams of the process object are being handled and the stderr stream is being redirected to the output.

My question is: Is there a way to "emulate" a console so that the external sub-process's System.console() call returns a valid console object that is hooked to my primary (parent) application?

Code for process builder below:

```
final ProcessBuilder Builder = new ProcessBuilder("\"" + System.getProperty("java.home") + "\\bin\\java.exe\"", InitMemArg, MaxMemArg, "-jar", "\"" + MCServer.getName() + "\"");
Builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

Comment: If Java API does not allow you to emulate console, you could create a native wrapper utility, which will provide fake console for the secondary Java app, and provide main Java app with just stdio channels.

Comment: @hyde
I was thinking about that as well, but I'm trying to maintain cross-platform compatibility and I really don't want to write a tiny "fake" console application for every OS out there...

Comment: Well, there are standard applications under both Windows and Linux: `cmd.exe` and `x-terminal-emulator`... ;) And "console" is pretty OS-dependent concept anyway, once you go beyond stdio stuff. When you have an external application which expects a "real" console, things get hard.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you will have to make a Thread that creates a [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class that appears to the 3rd party application as a console, before you start the 3rd party process.

This console will also have to communicate with your GUI application.

Comment: A Console object cannot be "created" (has a private constructor) it is loaded (created) by the JVM automatically at runtime.